How to comprehend and collect a value from a complex list using the Alpaca API?
request_close = StockLatestTradeRequest(symbol_or_symbols = "TSLA", start = datetime.now(), timeframe = TimeFrame.Minute, limit = 1) 
price = [{x['p']} for x in data_client.get_stock_latest_trade(request_close)["TSLA"]][0].pop()
print(price)

I'm trying to use a different method in the alpaca API as seen above, but it doesn't work because the output is different. How am I supposed to format it?
I tried doing this to comprehend the list:
price = [{x['p']} for x in data_client.get_stock_latest_trade(request_close)["TSLA"]][0].pop()
print(price)

But the code doesn't work for the specific output that the get_stock_latest_trade has.

Is there supposed to be a difference between the first and the second code?

"it doesn't work because the output is different" - different from what?

I don't understand what "different method " you try to use. And I dont' see any difference in both code. And I can't see output so I don't understand how "the output is different". We can't run your code, we can't see your computer, and we can't read in your mind - you have to describe all details in question (nor in comments)

Before This method I used this one to find the most recent closing price of a stock:
request = StockBarsRequest(symbol_or_symbols = "TSLA", start = datetime.now().replace(hour = 0, minute = 0, second = 0, microsecond = 0), timeframe = TimeFrame.Day, limit = 1)'  'close = [{x['c']} for x in data_client.get_stock_bars(request)['TSLA']][0].pop()'  'print(close)
The output of this method was a Union[BarSet, RawData] So the code above worked.
The method Im using in the question has an output of: Union[Dict[str, Trade], RawData] So It doesn't work.

Lets look at the return types of the two functions you reference:
get_stock_bars() has a return type of Union[BarSet, RawData]. And if we look further, a BarSet is Dict[str, List[Bar]]
So your code works because you access the value associated with the "TSLA" key in the dictionary. That value you accessed is a list, so you are able to access the first item of that list.
get_stock_latest_trade() has a return type of Union[Dict[str, Trade], RawData]. If we look further, we can see that a Trade is just a dictionary of values. All you need to do is use the 'p' key to access the price value.
For your code to work:
request_close = StockLatestTradeRequest(symbol_or_symbols="TSLA")
price = data_client.get_stock_latest_trade(request_close)["TSLA"]['p']
print(price)

Another note: StockLatestTradeRequest only has two parameters:

symbol_or_symbols (which is required)
feed (which is optional)

So I am not sure why you had there was a start, timeframe, and limit parameters when you wrote the code.
References: https://github.com/alpacahq/alpaca-py/
